# Обособление "однажды" в тексте

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Хотелось бы уточнить актуальность слова ***однажды*** в данном предложении:
**Возможно, однажды, наши боги смогут стать друзьями.**

А также хочу понять: в каких случаях слово ***однажды*** обособляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "однажды" является наречием и само по себе обособления не требует. Поэтому в вашем примере вторая запятая после "однажды" не нужна.

*Возможно, однажды наши боги смогут стать друзьями — а также поинтересоваться, в каких вообще случаях слово **однажды** обособляется.*

Употребление слова "однажды" в данном случае абсолютно корректно. Здесь оно употреблено в смысле "когда-нибудь".

*ОДНАЖДЫ,* наречие.
**1.** Один раз. Я видел вас только о. Такое случается лишь о. Я не о. говорил тебе об этом.
**2.** Как-то раз, когда-то. О. заговорили о давно забытом событии. О. я понял всю правоту этих слов и с тех пор ни разу не забывал о них. О. мы все пили чай на террасе.
**3.** *Когда-нибудь.*
**Пройдут годы, и однажды ты проснёшься знаменитым.

Уверяю вас, однажды наступит момент полного прозрения!

Однажды ты вспомнишь обо мне и загрустишь.**

Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше так: **Возможно, когда-нибудь наши боги смогут стать друзьями.**

Семантика наречия "однажды" во всех значениях связана с каким-то моментом, поэтому в один момент (однажды) друзьями не становятся.

Наречие *однажды* не обособляется, но может уточняться другим наречием:

Я хорошо помню, как **однажды, в 1905 году,** в одном "литературном" доме хозяева и гости часа полтора шёпотом гадали: придёт или нет? [В. Ф. Ходасевич. Брюсов (1924)]